# SequelizeDatabaseError: Sending the error in the response

Tags: javascript, error-handling, sequelize.js, postman

Logging an error and sending it back in the response gives entirely different results even though it is the same variable!

> adminservices.js

```
var updateAdminById = function(new_admin_data, callback) {
  logger.info("new_admin_data: " + JSON.stringify(new_admin_data));
  logger.info("new_admin_data.id: " + new_admin_data.id);

  models.admin
   // .update({ admin_password: passwordCypher }, { where: { id: admin_id } })
    .update(new_admin_data, { where: { id:new_admin_data.id } })
    .then(function(admin) {
      callback({
        Update: true,
        admin
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      callback({
        Update: false,
        error
      })
    });
};
```

> admin_routes.js

```
router.post("/updateAdminAccountById", function(req, res) {
  adminService.updateAdminById(req.body, (updateData) => {
    if (updateData.update) {
      //Update is succesfull return updated admin data
      res.status(200).json(updateData.admin)
    } else {
      //Update failed return error
      logger.error(updateData.error);
      res.status(400).json(updateData.error)

    }
  })
});
```

In the terminal, logging the error gives this:

> 2020-02-06T12:02:24+0100  admin_routes.js:459 
>   SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input value for enum enum_admins_role:
>   "Administrateur"
>   But, the response in POSTMAN is this:

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 179,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22P02",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\enum.c",
        "line": "133",
        "routine": "enum_in",
        "sql": "UPDATE \"admins\" SET \"nom\"=$1,\"email\"=$2,\"mot_de_passe\"=$3,\"role\"=$4,\"id\"=$5,\"updatedAt\"=$6 WHERE \"id\" = $7",
        "parameters": [
            "NewUpdatedValue",
            "NewEmail",
            "NewPassword",
            "Administrateur",
            "29",
            "2020-02-06 11:02:23.391 +00:00",
            "29"
        ]
    },
    "original": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 179,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22P02",
        "file": "d:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\enum.c",
        "line": "133",
        "routine": "enum_in",
        "sql": "UPDATE \"admins\" SET \"nom\"=$1,\"email\"=$2,\"mot_de_passe\"=$3,\"role\"=$4,\"id\"=$5,\"updatedAt\"=$6 WHERE \"id\" = $7",
        "parameters": [
            "NewUpdatedValue",
            "NewEmail",
            "NewPassword",
            "Administrateur",
            "29",
            "2020-02-06 11:02:23.391 +00:00",
            "29"
        ]
    },
    "sql": "UPDATE \"admins\" SET \"nom\"=$1,\"email\"=$2,\"mot_de_passe\"=$3,\"role\"=$4,\"id\"=$5,\"updatedAt\"=$6 WHERE \"id\" = $7",
    "parameters": [
        "NewUpdatedValue",
        "NewEmail",
        "NewPassword",
        "Administrateur",
        "29",
        "2020-02-06 11:02:23.391 +00:00",
        "29"
    ]
}
```

My question is not why I am having this error. I have succesfully fixed it. My questions are:
**How come the error is displayed differently in the terminal and in POSTMAN if it is the same variable?**
**Why doesn't the error description appear in POSTMAN like it appears in the terminal?**

Answer (score 0):

`SequelizeDatabaseError` is descendant of `BaseError` which in turn descendant of `Error`.

`Error` redefines `.toString()` to print instance's name and message properties like `'${name}: ${message}'` if both available.

For more details see:

- [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/errors/base-error.js~BaseError.html](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/errors/base-error.js%7EBaseError.html)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/toString